# Extraer fecha a partir de MailKit

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy usando la librería MimeKit para descargar correos de una cuenta, para después guardarlos en una tabla en sql server.
La fecha en MailKit viene como DateTimeOffset

> 23/07/2021 12:00:02 p.m. -06:00

Al intentar guardarla en la base de datos lanza un error porque no la puede convertir a una fecha válida. Después de revisarla noté que el problema es por el "p.m." que incluye la fecha. Lo primero que se me ocurrió fue hacer un substring y quitar todo lo que está de la **p** y adelante, pero también tengo fechas como

> 23/07/2021 06:00:02 p.m. -06:00

por lo que hacer substring ya no es opción. Lo único que se me ocurre es convertir la cadena a formato de fecha hora de 24 horas, pero no encuentro cómo podría hacerlo. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

¡Gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: probaste con SELECT CAST('2017-08-25' AS datetime); ?

Comment: 3 cosas: 1. Lectura recomendada https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 2. Podrías trabajar con un split de un espacio en blanco, tendrías 4 fragmentos: fecha + hora + am/pm + horas de diferencia con GMT. 3. Teniendo en cuenta el punto anterior, puedes crear la fecha asignando el formato que desees.

Comment: Creo que la pregunta está bien formulada, pero en fin. El objetivo de la pregunta es que desde ayer estoy buscando cómo hacer la conversión y no encuentro cómo, así que quería ver si había alguna librería para realizarlo, o si tenía que hacerlo a mano. Tu respuesta me indica que es a mano. Gracias por el apoyo. Saludos!